# Vm error during start up "hvm is required for this operation"

Tags: xenserver, virtualization

I have installed a new XEN server 6.0. I have created a new vm machine and select windows xp sp3 template. When i try to start this new vm an error appears with the following message "hvm is required for this operation".

Print Screen:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77338852/19-6-2012%2010-51-28%20%CF%80%CE%BC.jpg

How can i resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HVM is full-virtualisation, as opposed to Xen's para-virtualisation. This requires support from the CPU in the form of [VT extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_VT). Many BIOSes default to disabling VT support, so check in the BIOS that this option is enabled. If you don't see anything in the BIOS, verify that your CPU does actually have VT extensions. [ARK](http://ark.intel.com/) will have this information for Intel CPUs.

Comment: I found my processor in ARK and do not have VT-x support. It is a 64-bit Intel® Xeon® Processor 3.20 GHz, 1M Cache, 800 MHz FSB. Thanks a lot mgorven.